# How to pick first occurence of value and get column name

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe

```
     color    string   col_new   string.1    string.2
0    red       abc      qwer       abc         poi
1   blue       xyz      zxcv       123         xyz
2  green       pqr      uyit       tzv         pqr
3   pink       lmn      nbtw       lmn         lmn
```

For each color(which is unique in my case), I want to take value in `string` column, and find the first occurrence of that value in the same row and return the column name where I found the value

For eg.

`row 0 should return string.1
 row 1 should return string.2
 row 2 should return string.2
 row 3 should return string.1`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41255229/7515189) example but its implementing on a single series or column, I want this to search value across all columns in that row.

Comment: Would you want `NaN` if the value isn't found anywhere?

Comment: It will find the value for sure , that how we generated the original table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), compare by column `string` and get columns names by first `True`s by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
print (df.filter(regex='string\.\d'))
  string.1 string.2
0      abc      poi
1      123      xyz
2      tzv      pqr
3      lmn      lmn

s = df.filter(regex='string\.\d').eq(df['string'], axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)

print (s)
0    string.1
1    string.2
2    string.2
3    string.1
dtype: object
```

If want select all columns without first 2 use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
s = df.iloc[:, 2:].eq(df['string'], axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)
print (s)
0    string.1
1    string.2
2    string.2
3    string.1
dtype: object
```

---

If possible some row no match is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for avoid return first `False` columns:

```
print (df)
   color string col_new string.1 string.2
0    red    abc    qwer      abc      poi
1   blue    xyz    zxcv      123      xyz
2  green    pqr    uyit      tzv      pqr
3   pink    lmn    nbtw      lmn      lmn
3   pink    lmn    nbtw      ttt      rrr <- no lmn values in another columns


mask = df.filter(regex='string\.\d').eq(df['string'], axis=0)
out = np.where(mask.any(axis=1), mask.idxmax(axis=1), np.nan)
print (out)
['string.1' 'string.2' 'string.2' 'string.1' nan]
```

Original solution return wrong output:

```
print (df.filter(regex='string\.\d').eq(df['string'], axis=0).idxmax(axis=1))
0    string.1
1    string.2
2    string.2
3    string.1
3       color
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   color string col_new string.1 string.2
0    red    abc    qwer  abctyrf      poi
1   blue    xyz    zxcv      123      xyz
2  green    pqr    uyit      tzv      pqr
3   pink    lmn    nbtw      lmn      lmn

#default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
#column for test
st = df['string']
#for eac hrow is tested subtring by st
s = df.filter(regex='string\.\d').apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(st.loc[x.name]), axis=1)
print (s)
   string.1  string.2
0      True     False
1     False      True
2     False      True
3      True      True
```

Comment: Was just about to post the very same...grrr :p

Comment: Is the `2` denoting which column to consider for picking value?

Comment: The original solution worked. Is there possible to set filter for what column name I can  look in? In my case there are over 1100 columns and in some rows the value I look for occurs in `col_new`, but I know for sure it will always occur in `string.some_number`. Can I set it to look for only in those columns which have `df.columns.str.contains('string')`

Comment: @MurtazaHaji - Answer was edited. Better is use `regex` parameter for find pattern `string.number`

Comment: Awesome, this worked out for me. I would suggest keeping original answer of picking value column by index as an option as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211903/discussion-between-murtaza-haji-and-jezrael).