# Pandas - find occurrence within a subset

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm stripping values from unformatted summary sheets in a for loop, and I need to dynamically find the index location of a string value after the occurrence of another specific string value. I [used this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255215/pandas-find-first-occurrence) as my starting point. Example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Small'],['Total',4],['Medium'],['Total',12],['Large'],['Total',7]])

>>>df
        0     1
0   Small   NaN
1   Total   4.0
2  Medium   NaN
3   Total  12.0
4   Large   NaN
5   Total   7.0
```

Say I want to find the 'Total' after 'Medium.' I can find the location of 'Medium' with the following:

```
MedInd = df[df.iloc[:,0]=='Medium'].first_valid_index()

>>>MedInd
2
```

After this, I run into issues placing a subset limitation on the query:

```
>>>MedTotal = df[df.iloc[MedInd:,0]=='Total'].first_valid_index()
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Still very new to programming and could use some direction with this error. Searching the error itself it seems like it's an issue of the ordering in which I should define the subset, but I've been unable to fix it thus far. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
So I ended up resolving this by moving the subset limitation to the front, outside the first_valid_index clause as follows (suggestion obtained from [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/9wi6vb/python_indexing_question/e9ktuh2/)):

```
MedTotal = df.iloc[MedInd:][df.iloc[:,0]=='Total'.first_valid_index()
```

This does throw the following warning:
*UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.*
But the output was as desired, which was just the index number for the value being sought.

I don't know if this will always produce desired results given the warning, so I'll continue to scan the answers for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `shift`:

```
df[df.iloc[:,0].shift().eq('Medium') & df.iloc[:,0].eq('Total')]
```

Output:

```
       0     1
3  Total  12.0
```

Comment: My actual data set has other data and blank spaces between the 'Medium' and 'Total' rows, which I believe might be contributing to the result I'm getting, which is an empty dataframe. Suggestions for how to account for this with the ```shift``` method?

Comment: If that’s the case, you should try to reflect it with the sample data.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. The format is highly irregular - I definitely missed some nuances when constructing a fake data-frame.

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
def find_idx(df, first_str, second_str):
    first_idx = df[0].eq(first_str).idxmax()
    rest_of_df = df.iloc[first_idx:]
    return rest_of_df[0].eq(second_str).idxmax()

find_idx(df, 'Medium', 'Total')
```