# How to get the first second-level index from a multi-index data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the Online Retail dataset from the UCI Machine Learning Repository in pandas, and I'm setting a multi-index consisting in `CustomerID` as first level, and `InvoiceNo` as second level. Here's the code:

```py
import pandas as pd


customers = pd.read_excel('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00352/Online%20Retail.xlsx')
customers.set_index(['CustomerID', 'InvoiceNo'], inplace=True)
```

```
                     StockCode                          Description  Quantity  
CustomerID InvoiceNo                                                            
17850.0    536365       85123A   WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER         6   
           536365        71053                  WHITE METAL LANTERN         6   
           536365       84406B       CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER         8   
           536365       84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE         6   
           536365       84029E       RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.         6   
           536365        22752         SET 7 BABUSHKA NESTING BOXES         2   
           536365        21730    GLASS STAR FROSTED T-LIGHT HOLDER         6   
           536366        22633               HAND WARMER UNION JACK         6   
           536366        22632            HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT         6   
13047.0    536367        84879        ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT        32   
           536367        22745           POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM          6   
           536367        22748            POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN         6   
           536367        22749    FELTCRAFT PRINCESS CHARLOTTE DOLL         8   
           536367        22310              IVORY KNITTED MUG COSY          6   
           536367        84969   BOX OF 6 ASSORTED COLOUR TEASPOONS         6   
           536367        22623        BOX OF VINTAGE JIGSAW BLOCKS          3   
           536367        22622       BOX OF VINTAGE ALPHABET BLOCKS         2   
           536367        21754             HOME BUILDING BLOCK WORD         3   
           536367        21755             LOVE BUILDING BLOCK WORD         3   
           536367        21777          RECIPE BOX WITH METAL HEART         4   
           536367        48187                  DOORMAT NEW ENGLAND         4   
           536368        22960             JAM MAKING SET WITH JARS         6   
           536368        22913          RED COAT RACK PARIS FASHION         3   
           536368        22912       YELLOW COAT RACK PARIS FASHION         3   
           536368        22914         BLUE COAT RACK PARIS FASHION         3   
           536369        21756             BATH BUILDING BLOCK WORD         3   
12583.0    536370        22728            ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK        24   
           536370        22727            ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE RED         24   
           536370        22726           ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN        12   
           536370        21724      PANDA AND BUNNIES STICKER SHEET        12   
           536370        21883                     STARS GIFT TAPE         24   
           536370        10002          INFLATABLE POLITICAL GLOBE         48   
           536370        21791   VINTAGE HEADS AND TAILS CARD GAME         24   
           536370        21035      SET/2 RED RETROSPOT TEA TOWELS         18   
           536370        22326  ROUND SNACK BOXES SET OF4 WOODLAND         24   
           536370        22629                  SPACEBOY LUNCH BOX         24   
           536370        22659              LUNCH BOX I LOVE LONDON        24   
           536370        22631             CIRCUS PARADE LUNCH BOX         24   
           536370        22661      CHARLOTTE BAG DOLLY GIRL DESIGN        20   
           536370        21731        RED TOADSTOOL LED NIGHT LIGHT        24   
           536370        22900      SET 2 TEA TOWELS I LOVE LONDON         24   
           536370        21913       VINTAGE SEASIDE JIGSAW PUZZLES        12   
           536370        22540           MINI JIGSAW CIRCUS PARADE         24   
           536370        22544                 MINI JIGSAW SPACEBOY        24   
           536370        22492              MINI PAINT SET VINTAGE         36   
           536370         POST                              POSTAGE         3   
13748.0    536371        22086      PAPER CHAIN KIT 50'S CHRISTMAS         80   
17850.0    536372        22632            HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT         6   
           536372        22633               HAND WARMER UNION JACK         6   
           536373       85123A   WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER         6
```

In this case, how do I get the first invoice for every client? i.e how do I return only the invoice number `536367` for the client `13047`?

EDIT:
To be more clear, I don't want only the first occurrence of the invoice per customer. I want to keep the columns such as `StockCode`, `Description`, and `Quantity`.

In other words, I want to keep only the transactional information from the first invoice number per customer. Take the customer ID `13047` for example, the first invoice is `536367` so I want to keep the records of that invoice, but I want to remove the invoices `536368` and `536369` because it's not its first invoice. The result would look like this:

```
                     StockCode                          Description  Quantity  
CustomerID InvoiceNo                                                            
17850.0    536365       85123A   WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER         6   
           536365        71053                  WHITE METAL LANTERN         6   
           536365       84406B       CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER         8   
           536365       84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE         6   
           536365       84029E       RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.         6   
           536365        22752         SET 7 BABUSHKA NESTING BOXES         2   
           536365        21730    GLASS STAR FROSTED T-LIGHT HOLDER         6   
           536366        22633               HAND WARMER UNION JACK         6   
           536366        22632            HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT         6   
13047.0    536367        84879        ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT        32   
           536367        22745           POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM          6   
           536367        22748            POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN         6   
           536367        22749    FELTCRAFT PRINCESS CHARLOTTE DOLL         8   
           536367        22310              IVORY KNITTED MUG COSY          6   
           536367        84969   BOX OF 6 ASSORTED COLOUR TEASPOONS         6   
           536367        22623        BOX OF VINTAGE JIGSAW BLOCKS          3   
           536367        22622       BOX OF VINTAGE ALPHABET BLOCKS         2   
           536367        21754             HOME BUILDING BLOCK WORD         3   
           536367        21755             LOVE BUILDING BLOCK WORD         3   
           536367        21777          RECIPE BOX WITH METAL HEART         4   
           536367        48187                  DOORMAT NEW ENGLAND         4   
12583.0    536370        22728            ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK        24   
           536370        22727            ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE RED         24   
           536370        22726           ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN        12   
           536370        21724      PANDA AND BUNNIES STICKER SHEET        12   
           536370        21883                     STARS GIFT TAPE         24   
           536370        10002          INFLATABLE POLITICAL GLOBE         48   
           536370        21791   VINTAGE HEADS AND TAILS CARD GAME         24   
           536370        21035      SET/2 RED RETROSPOT TEA TOWELS         18   
           536370        22326  ROUND SNACK BOXES SET OF4 WOODLAND         24   
           536370        22629                  SPACEBOY LUNCH BOX         24   
           536370        22659              LUNCH BOX I LOVE LONDON        24   
           536370        22631             CIRCUS PARADE LUNCH BOX         24   
           536370        22661      CHARLOTTE BAG DOLLY GIRL DESIGN        20   
           536370        21731        RED TOADSTOOL LED NIGHT LIGHT        24   
           536370        22900      SET 2 TEA TOWELS I LOVE LONDON         24   
           536370        21913       VINTAGE SEASIDE JIGSAW PUZZLES        12   
           536370        22540           MINI JIGSAW CIRCUS PARADE         24   
           536370        22544                 MINI JIGSAW SPACEBOY        24   
           536370        22492              MINI PAINT SET VINTAGE         36   
           536370         POST                              POSTAGE         3   
13748.0    536371        22086      PAPER CHAIN KIT 50'S CHRISTMAS         80   
17850.0    536372        22632            HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT         6   
           536372        22633               HAND WARMER UNION JACK         6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas - find first occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255215/pandas-find-first-occurrence)

Comment: @Dr.MantisTobbogan not really, I've updated my question with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel like there's something a little shorter, but seems to work.  Pull out the invoice numbers, `groupby` the customer ID, pick first invoice in each group:

```
customer_ids = customers.index.get_level_values(0)
invoices = pd.Series(customers.index.get_level_values(1))
first_invoices = invoices.groupby(customer_ids, sort=False).first()
```

Result:

```
CustomerID
17850.0    536365
13047.0    536367
12583.0    536370
13748.0    536371
15100.0    536374
 
13436.0    581233
15520.0    581241
13298.0    581385
14569.0    581416
12713.0    581578
Name: InvoiceNo, Length: 4372, dtype: object
```

Then you can make a `list` of `tuple` pairs (Customer ID, Invoice ID) and use that to index the original data:

```
ids_invoices = list(zip(first_invoices.index, first_invoices))
customers = customers[customers.index.isin(ids_invoices)]
```

Result:

```
                     StockCode  ...         Country
CustomerID InvoiceNo            ...                
17850.0    536365       85123A  ...  United Kingdom
           536365        71053  ...  United Kingdom
           536365       84406B  ...  United Kingdom
           536365       84029G  ...  United Kingdom
           536365       84029E  ...  United Kingdom
           536365        22752  ...  United Kingdom
           536365        21730  ...  United Kingdom
13047.0    536367        84879  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        22745  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        22748  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        22749  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        22310  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        84969  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        22623  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        22622  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        21754  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        21755  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        21777  ...  United Kingdom
           536367        48187  ...  United Kingdom
12583.0    536370        22728  ...          France
           536370        22727  ...          France
           536370        22726  ...          France
           536370        21724  ...          France
           536370        21883  ...          France
           536370        10002  ...          France
           536370        21791  ...          France
           536370        21035  ...          France
           536370        22326  ...          France
           536370        22629  ...          France
           536370        22659  ...          France
           536370        22631  ...          France
           536370        22661  ...          France
           536370        21731  ...          France
           536370        22900  ...          France
           536370        21913  ...          France
           536370        22540  ...          France
           536370        22544  ...          France
           536370        22492  ...          France
           536370         POST  ...          France
13748.0    536371        22086  ...  United Kingdom
15100.0    536374        21258  ...  United Kingdom
15291.0    536376        22114  ...  United Kingdom
```

**The above is going to `groupby` the customer ID, regardless of where it is repeated in the data.**. I emphasize this because I see that in your expected output, some customers have multiple blocks of purchases (i.e. `17850.0` appears at the beginning and at the end).  I'm assuming you actually do want to group all customer IDs together... preserving the blocks of repeated IDs and grouping by them would be a more complicated `groupby` operation.

Comment: That gives me the first invoice per customer ID, which is great but I still need the transactional records from those invoices. I've updated my question with more information.

Comment: @franccesco see my update, this may be correct but see my note at the end

Comment: This definitely did the trick for me, thank you!